# Why is initializing an integer in C++ to 010 different from initializing it to 10?

Tags: c++

When an integer is initialized as `int a = 010`, `a` is actually set to 8, but for `int a  = 10`, `a` is set to 10.
Can anyone tell me why `a` is not set to 10 for `int a = 010`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because it's interpreting `010` as a number in **octal** format. And in a base-8 system, the number `10` is equal to the number `8` in base-10 (our standard counting system).

More generally, in the world of C++, prefixing an integer literal with `0` specifies an *octal literal*, so the compiler is behaving exactly as expected.

Answer (score 9):

**0** before the number means it's in [**octal**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) notation. So since octal uses a base of **8**, **010** would equal **8**.

In the same way **0x** is used for [**hexadecimal**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) notation which uses the base of **16**. So **0x10**  would equal **16** in decimal.

Answer (score 8):

In `C`, `C++`, `Objective C` and related languages a `0` prefix signifies an [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) literal constant, so `010` = `8` in decimal.

Answer (score 6):

Leading 0 in 010 means that this number is in octal form. So 010 means 8 in decimal.