# C++ cout output explanation please

Tags: c++, octal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why is initializing an integer in VC++ to 010 different from initialising it to 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359418/why-is-initializing-an-integer-in-vc-to-010-different-from-initialising-it-to)

This got me very confused, and I hope one of you can answer my question. How come this code will produce the output "116"?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << 0164 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code has been compiled with MSVC++ 2010 and g++ under Mac OS X.
"cout" can print '0' alone and '164' alone, but as soon '0' is the first digit in the number the output changes.

Comment: Thanks guys, I actually never thought of the octal issue! And the worst part for me is, now that you mention, I already knew it :) Anyway, thanks for the help, ALL OF YOU :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the 0 in front makes the number be interpreted as [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

```
0164 = 
 4 * 1 +
 6 * 8 + 
 1 * 64
 = 116
```

Or, via binary:

```
 0164 =
   0   1   6   4 = 
 000 001 110 100 =
 1110100 = 
 116
```

The same goes for [hexadecimal numbers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/hex/), you write them as 0x1FA for example.

Answer (score 2):

In C and its brethren, a number with `0` on the front is octal, not decimal.

Hence your number is `1 * 82 (1 * 64 = 64) plus 6 * 81 (6 * 8 = 48) plus 4 * 80 (4 * 1 = 4)` which equates to `116`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692286/what-is-0x10-in-decimal/692310#692310) for a large treatise on what hexadecimal and octal are in C.